Inifinite loop on updating Google Calendar event by script (trigger issue)
I wrote a script to add tags and modify color of Google Calendar events.
The script :

select some events based on date range
apply some rules on the selected events

The script itself work just fine and is launched on a timely basis.
However, if I set up a trigger based on the update event trigger, then :

script will launch OK
events are updated
each event updated triggers a new launch of the script
=> Infinite Loop.

There has to be something that I do not understand about this trigger. How to prevent thos multiples executions ? Basically, I would like to "disable" the trigger while the script is running.
Many thanks,
Nico.
Tried :

using tags to record the events already processsed, but I still have the issue if I force the update
implementing this function

The code is like :
var hasLock = new Boolean(false)

function onCalendarEvent() { 
  // lock to prevent multiple executions of script
  if(DEBUG) {
    console.log("Event based laucnh. Lock is " + hasLock)
  }
  if (hasLock == false) {
    hasLock = true
    if(DEBUG) { console.log("Calling function") }    
    colorizeEvents(0) 
    hasLock = false
  }
}

function onCalendarEvent() {
 // do stuff : select events and update them
}


Use an intermediate trigger function to disable the trigger for times while the triggered function is running

@cooper Could you direct me on how to do that ? How can I disable a trigger ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I wouldn't disable the trigger.  Let the trigger handler be the intermediate function that calls your function whenever there is a trigger but you can disable the redirection of the trigger being redirected to it while the function is running.

Tried to implement a simple lock based on a global variable but still have the problem :-(
